# Как найти файл по имени в папках командой из терминала?

Tags: linux, файлы

Какая команда Linux наиболее подходит подобного поиска?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для подобного поиска подходит команда find.

```
find . -name имя_файла -print
```

Comment: Если не секрет зачем "-print"? У меня на машине выводы с ним и без него выглядят идентично, есть ли скрытый смысл?

Comment: Лет 15 назад find без -print не печатал.

Comment: @avp, спасибо я этого времени не застал)

Answer (score 9):

Если совсем недавно создали файл, то нужно использовать следующие команды.

`$ sudo updatedb` - обновление базы данных файлов и каталогов в файловой системе;

Затем:

`$ locate -i "имя_файла/имя_каталога"` - нахождение и отображение полного пути к файлу или каталогу без учета регистра букв в указанном файле или каталоге.

Comment: А что если просто ls /home/*filename* 

Comment: По тем командам, что я написал, поиск производится по всей файловой системе, а не в конкретном каталоге, как у вас!

Comment: ls / -ищет везде..

Comment: Главное потом в этом списке найти то, что надо. Можно, конечно, `ls -lR / | less`, но всё же при наличии `find` глупо изобретать велосипед. `find` вдобавок много чего может делать.